# Самоизменяющийся бинарник (Self Modifying Binary)

Tags: golang, binary-file

Возможно ли создать самоизменяющийся бинарник на Go? К примеру, программа должна отобразить сколько раз она была запущена и время последнего запуска.

Допустим:

```
./goprogram
1 29.06.2019 14:10
./goprogram
2 29.06.2019 14:12
./goprogram
3 29.06.2019 15:10
./goprogram
4 30.06.2019 14:10
```

При этом ни каких дополнительных файлов или записей не должно создаваться.

На Purebasic довольно просто такое реализовать:

- Скомпилированный бинарный файл создаёт свою копию.
- Записывает в конец файла число.
- Замещает оригинал изменённой копией.
- При повторном запуске выводит записанное число.

Можно пример такой реализации на Go?

Comment: Пишите число в отдельный файл и всё.

Comment: в этом вся суть, ни каких записей в системе и ни каких дополнительных файлов не должно быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, чего вам хочется, небезопасно, и наверняка будет запрещено антивирусами и прочими системами безопасности. Не говоря уже о разнице в различных ОС. Тем не менее, можно сделать как-то так (обработка ошибок опущена для краткости):

```golang
type persistent struct {
    Magic   [8]byte
    Content int64
}

var p = persistent{
    Magic:   [8]byte{0xBA, 0xDD, 0xFA, 0xCE, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xCA, 0xCE},
    Content: 0,
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(p.Content)

    const size = int(unsafe.Sizeof(p))
    currentBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, size))
    err := binary.Write(currentBuf, binary.LittleEndian, p)

    newP := p
    newP.Content++

    newBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, size))
    err = binary.Write(newBuf, binary.LittleEndian, newP)

    currentBytes, newBytes := currentBuf.Bytes(), newBuf.Bytes()
    self, err := os.OpenFile(os.Args[0], os.O_RDONLY, 0755)
    selfBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(self)

    i := bytes.Index(selfBytes, currentBytes)
    copy(selfBytes[i:i+size], newBytes)
    newSelf, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "selfmodifying")
    _, err = newSelf.Write(selfBytes)
    err = os.Rename(newSelf.Name(), self.Name())
    err = os.Chmod(self.Name(), 0755)
}
```

Полный пример на Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/WQjUQb6X7es.

Comment: Можете подсказать, как таким же образом записывать текстовые данные?

Comment: Текст придётся ограничить максимальной длиной и выделить ровно столько байт в структуре `persistent`, плюс выделить отдельно место под число символов, записанных сейчас (если вы конечно не хотите получить C-string).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, возможность реализации сильно зависит от
1) конкретной ОС и ФС
2) определения понятия "ни каких дополнительных файлов" (кстати, "никаких", если по обычным правилам языка, надо писать слитно; упоминаю это потому, что вообще проблемная трактовка, а значит, надо и такое уточнять).

Например, если допустимо, что в момент обновления счётчика создаётся временная копия (и есть права на создание в этом каталоге), то:

1. Надо ввести какую-то достаточно уникальную сигнатуру в файл. Это какая угодно константа, строковая или бинарная - по вкусу, лишь бы набор случайных байт, к которому по известному смещению будет приписан собственно счётчик. При этом на уровне программы эта сигнатура - глобальная переменная.
2. На обновлении, программа создаёт рядом со своим prog - копию в виде prog.new, находит поиском эту константу и по вычисленному таким образом смещению обновляет значение счётчика.
3. Чтение при выполнении - обращается к переменной, в которой эта константа, и достаёт из неё счётчик.

В общем надёжнее со строками - потому что у бинарных структур может быть выравнивание, но в них можно искать слайсами бинарной последовательности.

Если такого нет, то писать в файл запущенной сейчас программы обычно невозможно - Unix такое не позволяет (все флаворы), Windows вроде тоже. Но можно сделать запись в дополнительные атрибуты файла (проверить, получится ли в конкретном случае). В Linux есть подсистема xattr и изменение этих атрибутов не блокируется фактом работы программы.

В любом случае учтите, что это может быть заблокировано множеством методов и условий - FS только для чтения, каталог только для чтения, демон слежения за состоянием FS, и т.п.

Comment: Про "никаких" - имелось в виду, что не должно быть создано каких либо дополнительных файлов в которые будет записываться и в дальнейшем с которого будет считываться информация.
Реализация продемонстрирована выше, за что огромное спасибо!
Если у вас есть более изящное решение такой задачи, то буду крайне признателен если вы продемонстрируете это на примере кода.